# access vba array - subscript out of range error #9

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

say I have a table with column A, B & C and I have the following codes to find the column names and I want to join these names as array like "A B C". However, it returns with subscript out of range run time error9. What I should do to get rid of this error? Thanks in advance!

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub check_tbl2_Click()
Dim ind() As String
Dim joinInd As String
Dim l As Integer
For l = 0 To CurrentDb.TableDefs("tbl2").Fields.Count - 1
  MsgBox (CurrentDb.TableDefs("tbl2").Fields(l).Name)
  ind(l) = CurrentDb.TableDefs("tbl2").Fields(l).Name
Next l
joinInd = Join(ind)
MsgBox (joinInd)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You never set the dimensions for ind().  Here's one way to do it. Look at the redim statement.

```
Sub check_tbl2_Click()
    Dim ind() As String
    Dim joinInd As String
    Dim l As Integer
    ReDim ind(CurrentDb.TableDefs("tbl2").Fields.Count - 1)
    For l = 0 To CurrentDb.TableDefs("tbl2").Fields.Count - 1
        MsgBox (CurrentDb.TableDefs("tbl2").Fields(l).Name)
        ind(l) = CurrentDb.TableDefs("tbl2").Fields(l).Name
    Next l
    joinInd = Join(ind)
    MsgBox (joinInd)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

**EDIT:** Actually, Tom Collins' answer is much better if you decide to keep with the array method, so don't use this.  I wasn't thinking most efficiently.

```
Private Sub check_tbl2_Click()
    Dim ind() As String
    Dim joinInd As String
    Dim l As Integer

    ReDim ind(1)

    For l = 0 To CurrentDb.TableDefs("tbl2").Fields.Count - 1
      'MsgBox (CurrentDb.TableDefs("tbl2").Fields(l).Name)
      ReDim Preserve ind(UBound(ind) + 1)
      ind(l) = CurrentDb.TableDefs("tbl2").Fields(l).Name
    Next l

    joinInd = Join(ind)
    MsgBox (joinInd)
End Sub
```

but why not just:

```
Private Sub check_tbl2_Click()
    Dim joinInd As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim fld As DAO.Field

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    For Each fld In db.TableDefs("tbl2").Fields
        joinInd = joinInd & fld.Name
    Next

    MsgBox (joinInd)

    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```